# I need clarification on $\delta$ - derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, fractional-calculus

Please can someone tell me more about $\delta$ -derivative ($\delta=x\dfrac{d}{dx}$) as it appears in the Hadamard definition of frational derivative or elsewhere. Why, when or where we use it. Does anything the usual derivative ($\dfrac{d}{dx}$) does that the $\delta$ -derivative does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was taught its name was the $\theta$ operator, or homogeneity operator. You can easily see that its eigenfunctions are the monomials $1,x,x^2, \dots$ This operator appears in [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_homogeneous_function_theorem).

You can find a little more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_operator)